# SwiftUI UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 Terminated=disconnect method

Tags: ios, swiftui

*Xcode 14.0 (14A309), iOS Deployment Target 15.0*

- Main NavigationView #1 > NavigationView #2 > NavigationView #3
- SwiftUI View FileDownloaderView with a .fileImporter() attached to a VStack
- The FileDownloaderView is a subView of the NavigationView #3

When I select a file with the fileImporter or when I cancel the fileImporter, the view comes back to navigationView #1 instead of navigationView #3, with the following log message:

```
The view service did terminate with error:
Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
```

It worked fine before, but I probably made some changes elsewhere in the code that lead to this disconnection or something being nil in one of the navigationViews. I'm not able to find the error, neither a way to identify the exact location/moment where it fails.

Any help to improve debugging or to understand what could trigger this type of error?

Thank you. Philippe.

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same error in XCode 15.1 with iOS 17.2 as deployment target. All of the below assumes that one has modified the "Custom iOS Target Properties" to have an entry "Supports Document Browser" with value "TRUE". Reinstalling XCode did not fix this issue for me.

The following is enough to reproduce the error (both when one cancels the file import and when one selects a file):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isImporting = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Import") {
                isImporting = true
            }
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $isImporting, allowedContentTypes: [.json]) { result in
            print("importing")
        }
    }
}
```

**The "importing" is printed even when the error is thrown, meaning the onCompletion callback of the fileImporter is correctly called in either case. Also in practice I have found that whether the import actually succeeds or not is completely unrelated to whether this error shows or not.**

In one case my import failed because I was trying to import a file from outside the app documents folder (i.e. the folder named like my app shown under "On My iPhone" in the Files app or the FileImporter menu). Manually copying it to that folder before import allowed me to import it. In both cases the above error still displayed in the debugger and no other error was thrown.

In another case my import failed because I was trying to decode a JSON file with NULL values (i.e. optional properties) using `decode` instead of `decodeIfPresent`. Whether the import worked or not, the above error was displayed in the debugger, and it was the only error displayed!